# Error calling awk script from bash script

Tags: bash, awk

Is the following the right way to call the awk script Analyze_Stat.awk from a bash script? The awk script works fine when executed from the command prompt. I am trying to pass arguments $4, $5, $6 as values to the variable Threshold in the awk script, is the syntax correct? Thanks.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 #arguments passed
 if [ "$#" -ne 6 ]
 then
    echo "Enter all arguments: Stat_Type Host Date(yyyymmdd) R1 R2 R3"
    exit
 fi

 Stat_File="/path/to/stat/"$1"."$2"."$3"*.stat"

 k=4
 for i in  {'Stat1','Stat2','Stat3'}
 do
    `grep -i $i $Stat_File > "Temp/"$i".out"`
    `awk -v Threshold="$"$k -f Analyze_Stat.awk "Temp/"$i".out"`
    k=$((k+1))
 done
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/.

Comment: Why do you have `\`` surrounding `grep` and `awk` commands?

Comment: @Kugelman: Thanks for the reference, very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what behavior you expect by executing grep and awk in command substitution (backquote). If you have exactly three iterations, hardcode these three steps is the most simple solution :-)

```
grep -i 'Stat1' $Stat_File | awk -v Threshold="$4" -f Analyze_Stat.awk
grep -i 'Stat2' $Stat_File | awk -v Threshold="$5" -f Analyze_Stat.awk
grep -i 'Stat3' $Stat_File | awk -v Threshold="$6" -f Analyze_Stat.awk
```

If you prefer a loop, I suggest the following:

```
shift 3; i=1
for arg in "$@"; do
    grep -i "Stat$i" $Stat_File | awk -v Threshold="$arg" -f Analyze_Stat.awk
    let i++
done
```